# Google Play: change the image/text used for share

Tags: android, google-play

When users tap **'share'** on the Google Play App and use Facebook, a random image (from the ones I uploaded when I submitted the app) is used.

Could I change this image? Also, I want to know if I could change the text used for sharing via Whatsapp, Twitter, etc.

Thanks!